# Versioning combined CSS files in Laravel 5.4 with Laravel Mix

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

I am using Laravel Mix  in Laravel 5.4 and I would like to combine to plain files and add versioning.

Reading the documentation it says

> The version method will automatically append a unique hash to the
>   filenames of all compiled files, allowing for more convenient cache
>   busting

And it efectively does what it says. But is there any workaround to obtain a final combined file with versioning?

Actually I would like to join some compiled files together with other plain files and combine everything in a single versioned file.

**Edit:**

The code I am using is like the following

```
mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .combine(['public/css/app.css', 'other/component/file.css'], 'public/css/all.css')
   .version();
```

And I would like to obtain a versioned `all.css` file. i.e. something like `all.d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.css`.

However what I get is a versioned version of the `app.css` and a non-versioned version of the `all.css`.

Comment: Can you show the code you have so far and an example of your desired output?

Comment: Sure, I am editing the question

Comment: Try updating `laravel-mix` to at least 0.7.4. https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/352

Comment: Upgrading doesn't help. It looks like the funcionality i am looking for is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Versioning/Cache-Busting for CSS and JS files**

**Webpack.Mix**

After combining my css (using mix.styles) and js (using mix.scripts) files into two files, I had all.css and all.js.

To add versioning, I did the following:

```
var timestamp = Date.now();
mix.copy('public/css/all.css', 'public/css/all/all.'+ timestamp + '.css');
mix.copy('public/js/all.js', 'public/js/all/all.'+ timestamp + '.js');
```

OR

Write it directly when you combine your css and js files, for example:

```
mix.styles([
    'public/css/app.css',
    'public/css/custom.css'], 'public/css/all/all.'+ Date.now() + '.css').

mix.scripts([
    'public/js/app.js',
    'public/js/custom.js'], 'public/js/all/all.'+ Date.now() + '.js').
```

**Blade layout file:**

I created /css/all/ and /js/all/ directories. I used the [scandir() php function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) with ordering to get all of the files in the respective directories. Then I got the first filename from the array, which in this instance was 'all.1574160664960.css'.

```
@php($css_files = scandir('css/all/', 1))
<link href="/css/all/{{ $css_files[0] }}" rel="stylesheet">

@php($js_files = scandir('js/all/', 1))
<script src="/js/all/{{ $js_files[0] }}"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

https://laravel-mix.com/docs/5.0/versioning

In webpack.mix.js:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.sass', 'public/css')
   .version();
```